# Webdriver.io: Is there a way to click text?

Tags: webdriver-io

In **Webdriver.io**, is there a way to click (an element by its) text?

e.g.
a person has clicked and opened a drop-down menu and now wishes to click and select the desired element by its text.

Answer (score 7):

```
.click('h1=Welcome to my Page')
```

http://webdriver.io/guide/usage/selectors.html
Element with certain text

Comment: In my case, I could **not** use the _partial selector_ `*` for element type. WebDriver was unable to locate the element.

However, since my desired element was nested at some level inside a `div`, I managed to do this successfully:

`.click('div=Welcome to my Page')`

Comment: I believe partial text matching is meant to be used like, `.click('div*=Welcome to my')` , and the asterisk has no relation to the tagname. What happens when you try to reach the element you want to target explicitly using the element tagname itself (instead of a parent)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this
//*[text()='match']

Answer (score -1):

You can pick any element with a text using xpath selectors.
So you go like this:

```
browser.$('//*[text()="text you are looking for"]').click()
```

The *"//"* stands for any part of the HTML document object model (https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp)

`*` represents any HTML tag. If there is a `<div>` you can use a *//div*, if there is `<p>` you can use *//p*.

If you want to use just a part of the text you can use *contains* like this:

```
browser.$('//*[contains(text(), "part of text"]').click()
```

You can find about more about selectors in webdriver.io here:
https://webdriver.io/docs/api/browser/$.html

And more about xpath in here:
https://devhints.io/xpath